# session().getAtribute returning null JSF

Tags: session, jsf

My code below is returning null when I try print the person's name.
The session.setAttribute userLogged it's ok but the another session.setAttribute called currentUser returns null.
Can you help me?

```
    public String returnLogin(){

    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    EntityManager manager = getManager();
    PersonDAO dao = new PersonDAOJPA(manager);
    if (dao.login(getPerson().getEmail(), getPerson().getPassword())){
        ExternalContext ec = fc.getExternalContext();
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) ec.getSession(true);
        session.setAttribute("currentUser", getPerson());
        Person p = (Person) session.getAttribute("currentUser");
        session.setAttribute("userLogged", true);
        boolean temp = (boolean) session.getAttribute("userLogged");
        System.out.println(p.getName());
        setLogged(temp);
        System.out.println(isLogged());
        return "/index.xhtml" + "?faces-redirect=true";
    }
    else{
        FacesMessage ms = new FacesMessage("Email or Password Incorrect");
        ms.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
        fc.addMessage(null, ms);
        return "/account.xhtml";
    }

}

<h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
                 <h:outputLabel for="email" value="Email"/>
                 <p:inputText id="email" required="true" value="#{peopleMB.person.email}"/>
                 <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Password"/>
                 <p:password id="password" required="true" value="#{peopleMB.person.password}"/>
                 <p:commandButton value="Login" update="growl" action="#{peopleMB.returnLogin}"/>                    
             </h:panelGrid>

    public String returnPrintOrder(){

    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpSession session = (HttpSession) context.getExternalContext().getSession(true);
    Person s = (Person) session.getAttribute("currentUser");
    System.out.println(s.getName());
    for(Product p: getProducts())
        System.out.println(p.getDescription());
    return "/pages/print_order.xhtml?faces-redirect-true";
}
```

Comment: dao.login() receive person's email and password but it's correct cause I successfully access. My problem it's the session.getAttribute("currentUser") returns null. I access the page with email and password, but when I print the name's person returns null.

Comment: Ok! I edit the question and I put the method where getAttribute it's called.

Comment: if `getPerson()` does not return `null` (as it does according to your observation. Otherwise, a `java.lang.NullPointerException` would have thrown too early in the conditional test itself), then there is absolutely no chance that `session.getAttribute("currentUser")` can return `null` (unless something is broken in very exceptional conditions such as using reflection). The exception thrown should be indicating a different cause.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need to get info from the session; only store that user in the session and use reference:

```
 public String returnLogin(){

    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    EntityManager manager = getManager();
    PersonDAO dao = new PersonDAOJPA(manager);
    if (dao.login(getPerson().getEmail(), getPerson().getPassword())){
        ExternalContext ec = fc.getExternalContext();
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) ec.getSession(true);
        Person p = getPerson();
        session.setAttribute("currentUser", p);
        session.setAttribute("userLogged", true);
        setLogged(true);
        System.out.println(p.getName());
        System.out.println(isLogged());
        return "/index.xhtml" + "?faces-redirect=true";
    }
    else{
        FacesMessage ms = new FacesMessage("Email or Password Incorrect");
        ms.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
        fc.addMessage(null, ms);
        return "/account.xhtml";
    }

}
```

Comment: what exactly doesn't work? Just make sure that getPerson() method works as expected